# Django - No encuentra la ruta del TEMPLATES al mismo nivel de manage.py

Tags: django

Colocando el directorio TEMPLATES a la altura de manage.py, no encuentra el archivo inicio.html ¿Qué sucede?

Los archivos quedan así ( y ya no encuentra los archivos):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',

        #'DIRS': [BASE_DIR.child('templates')],
        #'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR],
        #'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        #'DIRS': [],

        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    TemplateView,
)

# Create your views here.
class Home(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/inicio.html'
```

Comment: Si estas utilizando el modulo `unipath` (`Path`), el valor del `BASE_DIR` debe ser: `Path(__file__).absolute().ancestor(2)`. Inténtalo y dime si funciona.

Comment: De esa manera que propones me devuelve lo siguiente:   BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).absolute().ancestor(2)
NameError: name 'Path' is not defined

Comment: No estas importando `Path`, tienes que importarlo: `from unipath import Path`.

Answer (score 1):

;para cambiar la ruta de los templates debes ir a `settings.py` dentro de tu aplicacion

y buscar estas linea `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]` y cambiarla por la de tu preferencia.

## quedaria asi:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR], ### aqui cambias la ruta del los templates a la ruta raiz
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Bien ¿Y si es para poner la ruta a la altura de manage.py cómo habría que poner? Gracias.

Comment: esta editada para que quede en la raiz `BASE_DIR` donde esta manage.py :v

Comment: Sigue sin encontrar el template. ¿Qué ocurrirá?